# No overload for method 'Fill' takes '2' arguments during report

Tags: c#

I've an error during report in visual studio 2008 that "No overload for method 'Fill' takes '2' arguments". But I give 2 arguments in an other program. It works fine. But now it generate error at compile time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "ID")
    {
        this.admissionTableAdapter.Fill(this.Database1DataSet1.admission,Int32.Parse(txtCriteria.Text)); // this is error line
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select some search criteria.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use gotodefinition for Fill and see what is it taking

Comment: Ok Tahir I review your problem and finds that Fill method don't take more than 1 argumnet. I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920.aspx) link will help you.. Mark it as answered if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can view all the overloaded methods for fill . here is no overloaded method exists that take (DatatTbale, int) which is you are providing.

The possible overloads are following

> DataAdapter.Fill (DataSet)
>
> DataAdapter.Fill (DataTable, IDataReader)
>
> DataAdapter.Fill (DataTable[], IDataReader, Int32, Int32)
>
> DataAdapter.Fill (DataSet, String, IDataReader, Int32, Int32)

Comment: It's solved... the fill method takes as many arguments as u define. I simply goes to it's source code and define 2 arguments.